# How do I crash a daemon on ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, daemon

I have some sample PHP daemons running that do various things, the thing is I am using the php library [php daemon](https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon) which, upon a fatal error, should auto start the daemon and I am curious as to how to crash, exploit or other wise break a daemon so that it crashes.

Are their any common methods aside from `KILL`??

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a task that sleeps for x seconds, runs a fatal error (for example use a function/class that doesn't exist).

Is there a reason of not wanting to use the `kill` command?

Comment: Id need it to be a fatal error to cause the library to say - hey, auto restart.